# Upgrade From 5.16.2 to 5.20.x Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can I do a straight through upgrade or do I need to do incremental such as 5.16 to 5.17 then 5.18, 5.19, and finally 5.20? I ask as in pre 4.7 I encountered this as I recall when making a larger version jump.

Thanks!

Comment: For that particular jump I would just go straight. But of course as always do it on a copy of the site first or make a backup that you can restore.

Comment: Followed advise and no issues. Appreciate it!

Comment: Not sure how to mark question as solved. If someone can tell me how or simply do it would greatly appreciate it so as not to have clutter out there on the topic.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question and mark it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demerit was correct in his answer posted as a comment and it worked great! I followed this procedure:

> For that particular jump I would just go straight. But of course as always do it on a copy of the site first or make a backup that you can restore.

Comment: There's a little checkmark underneath the "0" and up-down buttons - you need to check that to mark it as answered.

Comment: Says I need to wait 2 days to accept my own answer.

Comment: Thanks @Demerit only took me 2 years to figure that out! ;)